# Regex to find match using at least the first three letters but optionally any or all of them

Tags: regex

Is there a better way to write a regular expression to find at least the first three letters of a word but optionally any or all of them.

If the target word is `interface` I want to be able to find any of these:

`int`
`inte`
`inter`
`interf`
`interfa`
`interfac`
`interface`

I know I can use on like this but I'm hoping there's a better way:

```
(int|inte|inter|interf|interfa|interfac|interface)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `word.startsWith(input)`? Does it _have_ to be a regular expression?

Comment: SO isnt here to do all the work for you. Show what you have attempted to do so far and we can guide you from there (even if it doesnt work). If you haven't tried, do so first then return with your attempt and update your question

Comment: According to the information you've presented, the following regex will work for you `\b\w{3,}\b`.

Comment: Even better, you can use `\b\S{3,}\b`! Or if you want to ensure it starts with `int` you can you this one `(?=int)\b\S{3,}\b`!

Answer (score -2):

To match the exact strings as provided, that is the way you would do it. If you are OK with any string following int, you can use wildcards [a-z] with a 0 to whatever you feel is OK  upper limit. The following expression will find any word starting with int, followed by 0 to 30 lower case letters.

```
^(int)[a-z]{0,30}$
```

You can also use a regex tester site to fiddle around with your expressions and see what works.

Comment: Why maximum of 30? `pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis` is the longest word in any of the major English language dictionaries ([according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_English)). That word is 45 characters in length. Also, who's to say this won't be used on other languages such as French with characters like `é`? This also only captures the `int` part of the word, which is likely not the target for the capture group that the OP is looking for. There may also be words that include hyphens or apostrophes (e.g. *The internet's amazing!* or *inter-allied*)

Comment: 30 was arbitrary- as I said in my post, whatever limit the OP is comfortable with. OP wanted a method of capturing partial strings of the word interface without having to define each possibility, which the a-z wildcard does.

In short, I answered the OP's question about the matching interface, not a hypothetical word. I showed OP that wildcard strings were a thing, and that string length is a thing. And pointed out to OP that there are tools available for learning more.

Comment: Yes I have a working model with the example given "(int|inte|inter|interf|interfa|interfac|interface)" and that works but I wanted something less clunky.  And to answer the other comment I can't allow any other characters until after the next space.  So "int e0" would be find as would "interface e0" but "interop mobile" would not be allowed.

Comment: Missed one piece of feedback on the last response:  I have to use regex because this isn't a script it's HPNA and all I have is a text box (not a script or program).  So there's no "language" to use.  The same could be said of searching in notepad++ for instance.